# LocalStorage overwrittes when a new user input is made after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, javascript-objects

I'm still learning javascript so I'm doing a To-Do List project following The Odin Project, this is my first time using localStorage too. I have 2 modules, one for controlling all DOM related stuff and the other is where the objects I need are created. I'm using an array to store all the user inputs as objects and then storing it inside the localStorage.

Everything seems to work as I want, even when I refresh the page the localStorage is still intact. However when the user makes a new input, the localStorage gets overwritten.

Here's what I'm doing:

First the user introduces the input

```
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        let todoData = addTodo();
        addTodoItem(todoData);
        closeModal(modalAdd, overlayBg);
    });
```

The `addTodo` function is called from another module

```
const addTodo = () => {
    let todosArray = [];
    let todoItem = getFormInput();
    todosArray.push(todoItem);

    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todosArray));
    let todoData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));

    return todoData;
}
```

Then the user input which is an object gets stored inside `todoItem`, it gets pushed into `todosArray` and then it gets inside the localStorage, after that I get the content of the storage and turn it into an array again to store it inside `todoData` for future use.

I think the problem is that when the page is refreshed or closed, the contents of `todosArray` dissapears which is why it overwrites the localStorage. I was thinking a solution might be use the contents of the storage and update somehow `todosArray` with it so the old data doesn't get lost after the user makes a new input after refreshing the page.

Comment: Welcome to SO, ANgeloDiMo. Please include a minimal working example in your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It seems that in your addTodo function, you didn't update the data that you store in the localStorage, therefore, the data is always overwritten.

Comment: `let todosArray = [];
    let todoItem = getFormInput();
    todosArray.push(todoItem); localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todosArray));` Read your code out loud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new array and overwriting your `todos` property in local storage each time you run `addTodo`.  You should first `GET` your current todos array from localStorage, then push the new item into it and then lastly set that new array back into localStorage and you will overwrite the old `todos` with a new one that has your newly pushed item in it.

```js
const addTodo = () => {
    const todosArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    const todoItem = getFormInput();
    todosArray.push(todoItem);

    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todosArray));

    return todosArray;  // i don't think this line is actually necessary either unless you are doing something else with this data on the page. 
}
```

Also as a side note, you should break the habit of using `let` to declare your variables unless you are going to change them down the line.  I would use `const` for each of these declarations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will have in mind your advice too :)